# Elastic APM: .net Agent not creating traceparent header

Tags: .net-core, elastic-apm

I have a few API services instrumented into elastic APM now, all using the .net agent. The way I imagined it would work is that the first HTTP request that arrived wouldn't have any APM details in the headers, so that first agent would create the traceparent header and attach to subsequent requests. Then my services would get connected in the service map etc.

I'm not seeing the traceparent header created, when I inspect a HTTP call to another service there are several APM-related headers (trace.id, several transaction. items etc), but no traceparent. I then see this call in the APM logs for the other service, but also listed as an external dependency - APM doesn't recognise it as a call to a service its instrumenting and does not connect them in the service map.

Do I need to do something in order to 'start' things off, so that a traceparent header is created?